# Scrolling in JQM Listview stopped working on some devices after upgrading Cordova's latest version

Tags: android, listview, cordova, jquery-mobile, touch

I have an Android App that has a ListView on the home page. After I recently upgraded to Cordova's latest version some of my App's users are complaining that they can't scroll the listview (which goes beyond the footer, hence need to scroll). Some are even complaining that they can't click on any of the listview items to get next window.

Can anyone please give any idea what's happening. I am using JQM with PhoneGap and it was working perfectly until now with close to 50,000 users base.

Regards